# Does Intel H97 support RAID5 and RAID1 at the same time?

Tags: raid

Can anyone tell me if modern mainboards with the Intel H97 chipset that claim to support RAID0, RAID1, RAID5 and RAID10 also support RAID1 and RAID5 at the same time given 6 SATA HDDs? What I want to do is create a RAID5 with 4 disks and RAID1 with 2 disks.

Comment: If the motherboard says it supports RAID1 and RAID5 then the maximum number of disks it supports will entirely depend on the configuration and feature set of the motherboard itself.  As for the specific portion of doing 2 arrays according to this [question's](http://superuser.com/questions/770839/can-i-setup-two-raid-arrays-on-a-single-intel-z97-controller?rq=1) answer which provided documented proof it is possible.  Appears the linked question is a nearly identical duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create multiple arrays on that chipset (practically any Intel RAID controller should support it, as far as I've ever seen), and for anecdotal proof I currently use 2 RAID1's on my z97 board.

I've heard in the past that the Intel RST may or may not have a 2 array limit, but I've never tried to do 3 arrays on a desktop board personally, so I'm not sure if that's true or not, or if it was a limitation, I'm not sure if it still exists.  Since you're only doing 2, this shouldn't be an issue for you. :)

If you're worried about it, ask the place you're going to buy it from if it supports it; if they say yes, ask if you can return it if it doesn't.  If they say yes, get that in writing. ;)